# Android - execute http request when connection is reestablished

Tags: android, http, service, http-request

Iy Android application when user clicks logout button I need to send a http request that unregisters that user from push notification service.

The user might click that button when there's no internet connection. In such case user should be logged out and the unregister http request should be executed when there the internet connection is reestablished. If there error code while executing the request it should be sent again.

Is there any open source library that enables such functionality out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a flag in shared preferences `"isAboutToUnregister":true` when the user clicks to unregister. Then when un-registration is complete set it to `false` or remove it.

Then you can check for it `onResume` and perform the unregister action when is `true`.

You don't mess with broadcasts, you don't mess with services.

You can even check the flag on a successfull push. (That means that the user is online and the unregistration process can happen then)